# webpack entry module not found

Tags: webpack, babeljs

When I run webpack, I get this error:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'game'
in /Users/frederikcreemers/dev/dark_chess
```

(newline added for clarity.)

But I'm certain that `game.js` exists.

Here's what my `webpack.config.js` looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "game.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "build",
        filename: "index.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: "babel?presets[]=es2015", exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/}
        ]
    }
};
```

I'm not sure how to further investigate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I ran jest, with everything set up according to the jest webpack tutorial, I got this message:

```
Using Jest CLI v0.8.2, jasmine1
 FAIL  __tests__/test_game.js 
● Runtime Error
Error: Missing setting "resolve.root" in /Users/frederikcreemers/dev/dark_chess/webpack.config.js
```

So I learned that the problem was a missing configuration value. Adding this to my `webpack.config.js` solved the issue for me:

```
 "resolve": {
    "root": __dirname
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The webpack [`entry`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry) option usually resolves to a [File Module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules).

So, probably what you need is to indicate the relative path to your `game.js` file module:

```
entry: "./game.js",
```

Otherwise webpack will try to load it as a core module or from `node_modules` folder.

> Without a leading '/', './', or '../' to indicate a file, the module
>   must either be a core module or is loaded from a node_modules folder.

Comment: Weird, it works with my entrypoint above, when i have `resolve.root` set in my webpack config.

Comment: Or you can set the resolve.root - won't need '/', './' or '../' in that case

Comment: this is the answer that helped me !

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell webpack to load modules (you `game.js`) from either `__dirname` or any path you defined. With webpack 2, there are two options:

Solution 1:
Add this to `webpack.config.js`:

`resolve: {
  modules: [__dirname, 'node_modules']
}`

Solution 2:
Prefix your `game.js` with `./` or something like `__dirname + '/game.js'`.